.exe installer not responding/disappears from windows screen while installing some packages
I have a flask  app which is converted to .exe using NSI compiler. Now when every time user runs the .exe file the exe is looking on some network drive for the packages to install and installing it on local machine to specified location the problem it is able to install few of the packages but at some point while installing packages it shows on windows screen "Not responding" and it disappears from the screen.
I tried running it multiple time to see if there is any specific package is causing this issue, is one intel package mkl-2019.4 which is causing this issue most of the time but not all the time to my surprise it is also failing on other packages which are less then 10mb
error logs

How are you converting the flask app? Can you post your .nsi?

When does it hang? On the Directory page or the InstFiles page?

I am converting by using  NSIS application , uploading my .nsi file to the application and letting the application compile and generate a .exe file
It hangs while installing packages required for the application to work @Anders

Added the error logs in the above post it is failing at different packages every time but most of the time it is failing at the mkl-2019.4 intel package shared in the above image

What does uploading my .nsi mean? Are you invoking makensis.exe?

A .nsi file is a script used by NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System), a tool for creating Windows installers. The .nsi script defines the instructions and configurations necessary to build an installer package. They NSIS provide an application where I can upload .nsi and it creates.exe file out of it.

I know what NSIS is. I was just confused by your usage of the word upload. We can't help you if you don't show us your .nsi file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
